# How can I select all id's from a sql table in descending order and then echo them (in php)?

Tags: php, sql, select, row

I have several id's in a table called "leaderboards" that belong to different users. They're named as:"***id_user***" and they're **not in order**. What I want to do is printing divs in a leaderbord which should contain some info that I get from those id_user's.

The only problem I have about it is that after a research on stackoverflow and other websites, I still couldn't find how to ***select*** those id_user's in ***descending*** order **AND** be able to take one by one to get the info from that user and then continue with the next id_user, and so on.

I don't know how to select the specific **row** of each **id_user** in **descending order** to do the other codes that I already know how to do.

I hope it's not a duplicate of any other previosly asked question on this website (I really did a research and I couldn't find any specific answer to this question, for the sql part and the php part all together).

Thank you so so much beforehand.

Comment: you can do a simple select * from leaderboards order by id_user DESC and then get the values in PHP. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is the problem that you want information from multiple tables, the sorting or both? And do you want it sorted by id or by some other value like some sort of score?

Comment: Yes, in part. Because everywhere I look for an answer or a partial answer, I only find the SQL code to do it, but not the php code to take each one of those results and use the id that each row contains to do other things I have to do previously in the code to print those results afterwords.

Comment: What I want is the SQL code to select all of those id's from only one table in descending order and then the PHP code to manipulate the information that each row contains (like a foreach do something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An INNER JOIN between your tables will achieve what you intend.

```
SELECT *
FROM users
JOIN leaderboards WHERE users.id = leaderboards.id_user
ORDER BY users.id DESC
```

In each returned row, you will get the columns from both your `users` and `leaderboards` tables, so loop over the result and echo the information from the user you need.

```
$query = 'SELECT...';
$res = mysqli_query($query);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    echo '<div>'.$row['id'].' - '.$row['username'].' - '.$row['image'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: Well, actually that helps me a lot. What I need from each user id is its profile image and its username. However, how can I manipulate each row that this sql selection does?

Comment: Ok, to help you further, I added some PHP code to loop over the result. Please read up the PHP documentation about "mysql_fetch_assoc" or similar functions, you will find a lot of examples.

Comment: I'm testing your answer right now and it fits better my needs. Thank you. I just want to ask you: How can I do to order the results in descending order      based on an "x" thing and in ascending order for a "y" thing? I was trying something like: ORDER BY leaderboards.time DESC AND ORDER BY leaderboards.distance ASC but it doesn't work

Comment: because I'm trying to display leaderboard places based on the distance and time that each user made for the virtual run they participated and already finshed. If all users completed the required distance for, for exampe, the 5 km virtual run, then If I use ORDER BY leaderboards.time DESC it works perfectly. However, if I want to also evaluate who made the highest distance and the shortest time to complete it, I get lost and don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Simply drop "AND ORDER BY". Ordering criteria are comma-separated, so write "ORDER BY leaderboards.time DESC, leaderboards.distance ASC". This kind of information is easy to find, so I guess you start reading MySQL documentation, or simply SQL standard, for example http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html
Thank you :)

Comment: Wow Anthony, you have made ALL of my work much easier by teaching me how to do that. Not only for that code but also to shorter all of my php codes. Great. You are my Nº1 best answer; You gained it.

Answer (score 0):

You could do with a good read up on both PHP and MySql but I'll give you a clue.

### EDIT

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `the_name_of_your_table` ORDER BY `user_id` DESC;";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        print $row["user_id"] . " - " . $row["username"] . "<BR>";
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time! actually it really helps me a lot. I just have one question:  What is "bar" for in the code?

Comment: Foo/Bar you will see dotted all over the place. They mean nothing at all they are just placeholders. As I don't know the name's of your database columns I've used foo and bar. But you could change these for $result['FirstName'] or $result['This_is_my_column'], they depend soley on the names of your columns. --> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar

Comment: So, if I do something like: **$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC); $id_user = $row["id_user"]; echo $id_user . "<br>";**  inside the **foreach** that you wrote, does it work properly?

Comment: Spectacular. Thank you so much! You've answered my question and solved my problem.

Comment: I've implemented the code with some small changes and it works except for the "**DESC**" which seems not to work. The SQL code I'm using is: **$query1 = "SELECT * FROM leaderboards ORDER BY id_user DESC";** and I get all the id's printed but in the same order they are in the table and not in descending order (I also tried with ASC but it seems not to work neither). What can I do?

Comment: I had a mistake. Your code works perfectly well. Thanks!